# openssl req -key server.key -out server.csr taking ages to complete

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I am trying to generate my own self-signed ssl certificate with openssl so I can test them out on a dev server on nginx before I buy one. I have created the server.key but when I run the command `openssl req -key server.key -out server.csr` it just hangs after the enter pass phrase

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when using `GitBash` in Windows 7, After hours of search this solved my issue:

```
winpty openssl genrsa -out ../private.pem -aes256 4096
```

Let me know if it helps anyone.

Comment: @Miere I am glad it helped you.

Comment: I've this problem using github on windows 10. I solved this by using openssl from WSL.

Answer (score 7):

You lack ***entropy*** - the randomness the server needs to generate the key.

Try moving the mouse, or hitting random keys on the keyboard - you should see progress when you do.

Alternatively, use this one-liner to generate a self-signed certificate with less steps:

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.crt`

Comment: Why is there entropy needed when the key already exists? Even though this solution works, I don't think entropy is the reason that the task does not complete.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The missing flag was `-new` which the command above specified but your original did not. @mjspier had the right answer: https://serverfault.com/a/929551/4603

Answer (score 2):

It seems you miss to specify the option `-new` to tell openssl to generate the certificate request. Not sure why openssl does not show any message in this case.

To generate the certificate request with an existing private key you can use:

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

To generate a self signed certificate with an existing private key you can use:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key server.key -out server.cert
```